# Table Row Data not getting Updated and Deleted in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4

I am building a sample project named : **Tennis Club Management** using Javascript,HTML,CSS,Bootstrap. In this project i have some HTML pages and one JS file like **index.html,profile.html,manageFees.html,index.js etc**. In **manageFees.html** a dynamic table gets generated using online **API** data on page load and also i have a button **Add Fees** which when clicked shows inputs in table for saving fees of clients along with **save** button, when i click on **save** button a table get displayed below showing the saved data which also contains two fonts for **delete** and **update**.

**The problem** is if table contains multiple records then, the delete icon works only on last row and when update icon is clicked for particular row then that row data should get displayed again in table inputs so as to make changes and save it again.

**JS Fiddle Link** https://jsfiddle.net/mohitsharma1991/Lruzv2mh/1/

**Below is the code file**

**manageFees.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Manage Fees</title>

    <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-9aIt2nRpC12Uk9gS9baDl411NQApFmC26EwAOH8WgZl5MYYxFfc+NcPb1dKGj7Sk" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <!-- ADDING STYLE.CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/style.css">

    <!-- ADDING FONT AWESOME  -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

</head>

<body onload="showfees()">

    <!-- ADDING BUTTONS LIKE SHOW MATCHES, ADD MATCHES USING CSS BOOTSTRAP -->
    <!-- <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary showfees" onclick="showfees()">Show Fees</button> -->
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary addfees" onclick="addfees()">Add Fees</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger showfees" onclick="showfees()">Back</button>


    <!-- ADDING SEARCH BAR -->
    <input type="text" class="searchbox" id="searchbox" onkeyup="mySearch()" placeholder="Search...">


    <!-- SORT BUTTON TESTING -->
    <button class="btn btn-warning sort" onclick="tablesort()">SORT</button>

    <!-- CREATING REGISTRATION PAGE FOR ADDING FEES -->
    <table class="feesregistration" id="feesregistration">
        <!-- <tr>
            <td>
                <label>ID :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="feesid" id="feesid">
            </td>
        </tr> -->
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Name :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" class="playerNameFees" id="playerNameFees" maxlength="40">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="playerNameFeeserror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Fees For :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="feesFor" id="feesFor">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="court">Court</option>
                    <option value="tournament">Tournament</option>
                    <option value="both">Both</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="feesForerror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Fee Type :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="feesType" id="feesType">
                    <option value="select">---Select---</option>
                    <option value="monthly">Monthly</option>
                    <option value="halfyearly">Half Yearly</option>
                    <option value="annually">Annually</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="feesTypeerror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <label>Date :</label>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="date" class="feesdate">
            </td>
            <td>
                <label class="feesdateerror"></label>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-success savefees" onclick="saveFees()">SAVE</button>
            </td>
            <td>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info clearfees" onclick="clearfees()">CLEAR</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <!-- ADDING BOOTSTRAP JS -->
    <!-- JS, Popper.js, and jQuery -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.0/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-Q6E9RHvbIyZFJoft+2mJbHaEWldlvI9IOYy5n3zV9zzTtmI3UksdQRVvoxMfooAo"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-OgVRvuATP1z7JjHLkuOU7Xw704+h835Lr+6QL9UvYjZE3Ipu6Tp75j7Bh/kR0JKI"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

    <!-- ADDING INDEX.JS -->
    <script src="/js/sidebar.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/index.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

**Below are the Screenshots**

[image: Dynamic table using online API on page load]

[image: Table input display on Add Fees Click]

[image: Input data in fields]

[image: table appears after saving the data]

[image]

[image]

**Any Solution Please ?**

Answer (score 1):

The way delete works; it is taking the **DOM** with a certain ID, and if you are generating the multiple data with the same ID then it is going to take the last one and delete it.

Comment: Issa: I am using row number as ID parameter which will always be unique but somehow it is not working